A problem about the charge conjugation of scalar $\bar{\psi}\psi$
When I read the Peskin & Schroeder book, I find the charge conjugation for scalar $\bar{\psi}\psi$ is given by
$$
C\bar{\psi}\psi C=-\gamma^0_{ab}\gamma^2_{bc}\psi_c\bar{\psi}_d\gamma^0_{de}\gamma^2_{ea}=+\bar{\psi}_d\gamma^0_{de}\gamma^2_{ea}\gamma^0_{ab}\gamma^2_{bc}\psi_c=-\bar{\psi}\gamma^2\gamma^0\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi
\tag{3.147}$$
Here the indices are spinor indices. It confused me that the second and third equals sign can hold. I want to know the detail of this derivation.

The second sign
$$
-\gamma^0_{ab}\gamma^2_{bc}\psi_c\bar{\psi}_d\gamma^0_{de}\gamma^2_{ea}=\bar{\psi}_d\gamma^0_{de}\gamma^2_{ea}\gamma^0_{ab}\gamma^2_{bc}\psi_c
$$
comes from swapping the Grassmann-odd $\psi_c$ and $\psi_d$.
The third sign
$$
\bar{\psi}_d\gamma^0_{de}\gamma^2_{ea}\gamma^0_{ab}\gamma^2_{bc}\psi_c=-\bar{\psi}\gamma^2\gamma^0\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi
$$
comes from swapping the anti-commuting $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^2$.

Thank you, I have another question. When consider $C\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi C=+\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi $, I always get the extra minus sign. It seems like I miss a minus sign when change the order of gamma matrix. Could you give me some steps to see this?

@likai, The proper way is to accept this answer and raise another question in a separate post.
